# How to implement SSO for a portlets that has been deployed in the Liferay Portal

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on

I have developed a Portlet and deployed it in the Liferay Portal. I have a few other applications which would require logging in. I would like to implement SSO for the whole portal so that i can avoid logging into individual portlets.
How do i achieve this? Can somebody brief the process in steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's out-of-the-box behavior: You typically only log in to the portal, never to individual portlets.

It's hard to judge which resource to recommend: "Liferay in Action" (despite its age), https://dev.liferay.com ([e.g.](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/-/knowledge_base/6-2/setting-permissions)), or [training](https://www.liferay.com/services/training/topics/developer-1) come to my mind. Choose one